# Wix Burn: Launch using -passive option as default

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn, passive-mode

I'm using Wix 3.8 Burn and looking for an event like OnExecuteApp. We can launch bootstrapper.exe using -passive option so that it would auto start its installation process.

(Note: Type "BootStrapper.exe /?" to see other options.)

**Question:** How can we default set bootstrapper.exe to launch as passive (i.e. using -passive option)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the WixStandardBA. You will have to write a custom bootstrapper application, which will have complete control over how it wants to handle the UI.